# Git Commits appear in Bitbucket but not in SourceTree

Tags: git, bitbucket, commit

I've recently been trying to merge in some changes from a number of branches, when I discovered that the changes I made have completely disappeared.

We use Bitbucket for our source code hosting, and use Git through SourceTree.

When I view the specific commit in the Bitbucket UI, I can clearly see that files have changed (and on the date it did).
[image: Bitbucket view of code]

If I look in Source Tree however, whilst the commit appears, there are no file changes in the UI. On top of this, if I do a search (or Git History) on any of the modified files,  no changes are displayed.
[image]

Has anyone come across this before, and maybe have any suggestions as to how I might fix this?

It seems really strange.

If I go back to that commit, and try and merge in, it says that I am "already up to date".

The other thing I find strange is that the dates in SourceTree and Bitbucket don't seem to correlate.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems to resolve with time. I think it has to do with them using a CDN, but I'm not sure. It's very inconvenient sometimes!

Comment: How long did it take for it to reappear?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because the OAuth token that was allowing Sourcetree to authenticate with Bitbucket had expired, and Sourcetree's authentication with Bitbucket was silently failing. You can check this in Sourcetree > Tools > Options > Authentication > Account > Edit > Credentials.

I found it easiest to fix this by changing to Bitbucket app passwords and using that in Sourcetree https://stackoverflow.com/a/40946844/13437842

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue...
For me it resolved with one observation, not sure if that is the same scenario for you guys. Still am giving how the way it solved for me. Hope it could help someone...

We have a branch where 2 members are working on the same branch. For easy understanding naming members as developer1 and developer2.

Developer1 has some changes, mean while developer2 committed changes.
Without taking latest pull developer1 tried pushing his changes where his commit succeeded but push not happened.

Developer1 did not observe that one not merged that.
So later when developer2 trying for commit it is committing but not pushing saying error as

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdQbj.png)

After developer1 commits only deevloper2 able to push changes..